# Rails4 Paperclip attachments not working in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm trying to upload Avatars to Users and it's working in development but not in production

Rails4, Heroku, S3, Paperclip, Devise

Everything is working fine in dev.  When I push to Heroku, run Heroku migrate , and try to update devise User page with an attachment(:avatar) image, it returns the image url as missing.

In heroku logs --tail it appears to run normally, even saving the image to S3 (I checked and they are saving in my S3 bucket).  Also if I pull pg database I can see the columns in the database associated with attachment images (4 columns).  In production the attachment file columns are empty when I check the database, so nothing is going to them, but they are stored in S3.

This is kind of weird?  I thought Paperclip Docs say that it will save to database and run validations before sending to server.

[image]

My Form

[image]

My view (index.html.erb)

`<%= image_tag post.user.avatar.url(:thumb) %>`

And here's my log after successfully saving to S3 (heroku logs --tail)

[image]

If I check the database, the columns for attachments are still `nil`

what confuses me is that this works in Development but not in production and appears to not have anything to do specifically with an S3 error.

what am I doing wrong??

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say the production db columns are empty - do you mean blank or they weren't created in the schema for the table?

Comment: They are in the schema and work properly in dev.  If I pull the production database from heroku, they are nil.

Comment: OK, could you post the migration file where those columns are added to the database? to confirm they are correct. Should be like: add_column :users, :avatar_file_name, :string ...

Answer (score 0):

Well, big time-waster.

I finally got so fed up trying to figure this one out I ended up going through all the motions for a 2nd and 3rd time and for whatever reason, it works now :\

-I added paperclip.rb (empty file) in config/initializers/

-I merged all my safe branches into master.

-Ran bundle install

-Pushed to github

-Ran Git push heroku master

-Ran heroku run rake db:migrate

This is the 3rd time running through those operations so I honestly do not know where the problem was but it is working now.

- Thanks @peterept for helping

Comment: I feel your pain. I love ruby and I love rails in concept. But I have to say any job I do in rails I spent 75% of the time chasing weird deployment/configuration/conflict issues.

Answer (score 0):

You form should have enctype="multipart/form-data" and the new version of paperclip force you to have this validation:

validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage/.*\Z/

Take a look at their documentation: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip